# Faster inequalities in C

Tags: c, performance, optimization, if-statement, inequality

Let's say we have these inequalities:

```
if (a*a+b*b>0) {
    ...
}

if (a*b+c*d>0) {
    ...
}
```

Obviously, both of them require 2 multiplications to evaluate.
The thing is, do we really need to calculate 2 full-precision products just to check whether these expressions are positive or not?
Is there any mathematical trickery that allows me to write those if commands without the need to evaluate 2 products?
Will it be faster?
Or perhaps the compiler takes care of making it as fast as possible?
Am I overthinking?

EDIT:
Well, that escalated quickly.
I just want to point out that I am speaking in general terms. I don't need such a micro-optimization in any project of mine anyway.
Also, yes, I could have omitted the first one for being too trivial. Possibly the second one is more interesting.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this an actual bottleneck in a real project?

Comment: In the first case, if either quantity is non-zero then the condition is true.

Comment: Why does the first inequality require the multiplications?  That will be false only if a == 0 and b==0, and true otherwise.

Comment: In the second case you probably can't do much better, given modern floating point.  You could attempt to special-case where there are no negative values and at least one multiply result will be non-zero, but the operations to do that would be as expensive as the multiplies, I suspect.

Comment: (It might help a little to think about which case is more likely -- true or false.  You want to optimize the more likely case.)

Answer (score 2):

Your "am I overthinking" question suggests me that you haven't found this to be an actual bottleneck by really profiling your code. So I'd say yes, you're just trying to do premature optimization.

**However,** if this really is a major performance-critical part of your application, then the only improvement I can think of right now is the following. Since squares of real numbers can never be negative, then "a squared is greater than zero" is equivalent with "a is not zero". So if comparisons are fast (well, that's relative -- faster than multiplication) on your architecture, then

```
if (a*a+b*b>0) {
    ...
}
```

can be written as

```
if (a || b) {
    ...
}
```

(provided that no corner cases arise. If the variables are signed integers or floating-point numbers representing real numbers, then this should be fine. If, however, there are some unsigned integer overflow or complex numbers involved, then you will have to perform additional checks, and at that point, it's hard to reason about the relative performance without true profiling.)

I don't have such a "clever" "optimization" for the second case in my mind, but perhaps someone else can come up with something similar -- ***if and only if it is absolutely necessary.*** Not otherwise -- code readability is preferred over performance when performance is not critical.

Comment: 3i*3i is negative... though I would assume the op would have mentioned using complex numbers.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Read my answer. Or read it carefully. I am very well aware of the existence of complex numbers, that's why I wrote "Since squares of ***real numbers*** can never be negative"

Comment: my statement was just saying we don't know a and b are real.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: But there is no preferred ordering of the complex numbers.  So `a > 0` does not make sense mathematically if `a` is complex.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah I should have probably stated somewhere that those are real numbers. No complex please. Also, no, I don't actively need this optimization in my codes. Mine is more of a "just-in-case" theoretical question.

Comment: This of course does pose an interesting question: What is the type of these variables? The OP talks about full-precision products, but quite frankly, they could be any type and have overloaded operators. Absolutely all best are off without further clarity in the question.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are unsigned integers, then `a*a+b*b` can be zero without either of them being zero.

Comment: @pascalcuoq Oh, actually, yes. Let me add that.

Comment: You could have just used a|b and avoided the short-circuit.  Modulo what Pascal just said.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming none of these expressions will overflow either because the types don't have a concept of overflow or because the values are in range. When overflow and potential wrap-around enters the picture (e.g. if `a` and `b` are `unsigned int`) different rules apply.

The first statement is obviously equivalent to

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0)
```

or

```
if (a || b)
```

which trades an extra branch for two multiplications and an addition.

The second statement is a bit more interesting: I'd think it could be reasonable to determine the signs of the operand and only do the actual math when `a*b` and `c*d` have opposite signs. In all other cases the condition can be determined without knowing the actual values. Whether the resulting logic is faster than the computations will depend on the types, I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

The first one will always be >= 0. It will be 0 if and only if `a` and `b` are 0, so it's equivalent to:

```
if (a || b) {
   ...
}
```

About the second one: if sign of `a` is equal to sign of `b`, and sign of `c` is equal to sign of `d`, then it's the same situation as above:

```
if (sign(a)==sign(b) && sign(c)==sign(d))
{
  if ((a && b) || (c && d))
  {
    ... > 0
  }
  else
  {
    ... = 0
  }
}
else
{
  if (sign(a)*sign(b)==sign(c)*sign(d))
  {
     ... <= 0
  }
  else
  {
    /* must do the actual product to find out */
  }
}
```

For a IEEE-754 compliant floating point number, the sign is at the MSb of each number.

For environments in which FP is emulated, there's one thing you can do to optimize a bit the comparison: you can avoid the additions, if you just compare the two results of the products, like this:

```
if (a*b>c*d) {
   ...
}
```

This is a bit faster because to compare two floating point numbers, you just compare them as if they were signed integer numbers, and a FP-less CPU surely will have resources to compare two integer numbers faster than the time it spends doing a FP software addition.

Comment: "the sign is at the MSb of each number" needs clarification.  Are you saying the endian-ness of integers correspond to the endian-ness of the FP numbers?  BTW: If C11, could use `int signbit()` from `<math.h>`.

Comment: I'm saying that the sign is at the left-most bit of the sequence of bits that comprises the number. So in a way, yes, they correspond each other. In fact, to compare two IEEE-754 numbers, you have to consider them as signed integers stored in memory as LE or BE sequences.

Comment: My web research indicates the endian-ness of IEEE-754 is not specified by spec, even the integer endian-ness may differ from FP on a given system. Please provide a reference that could help clear this situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242589/would-float-point-format-be-affected-by-big-endian-and-little-endian

Comment: Endianess refers how to store multibyte numbers in memory. When an IEEE-754 number is stored into memory in a machine like the x86, it is stored with the bits 0-7 of the number at the first memory address, then bits 8-15 at the next memory address and so on. That is, the mantisa will be stored in the first bytes, then the exponent, then the sign. This is because the x86 loads multibyte numbers that way, no matter if those numbers are later interpreted as integer numbers or floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Another rewrite (assuming you are using floats, they are [32 bits wide and IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) compliant, and the same size as int; yes, this is hacky and platform-dependent).

For the first case, you can use a single bitwise 'or' & 'and' (the and is used to ignore the sign-bit and the exponent, retaining only the mantissa; you can remove it if there cannot be any -0s):

```
if (*((int *)&a) | (*(int *)&b) & 0x7FFFFF) { // a*a + b*b>0
  ...
}
```

I really doubt that there is any similarly branch-less magic for the second case.

Comment: I *did* write "hacky and platform-dependent". OTOH, if it works, it *will* work faster...

Comment: Yes - no need for my esoteric comment (or this on to remain).