# g++ double precision arm vs intel

Tags: gcc, g++, arm, cross-compiling, double-precision

Here is an image showing an output of the same program in intel and then in ARM:

http://screencast.com/t/1eA64D4rF

Both show output from reading a binary file with the numbers in the first column being of double precision floating point format. Why is it that I am unable to obtain the correct result (like in the case of intel -- 41784.998495, 41784.998623) vs (-8.1974E+204f etc) on the ARM environment?

The arm processor I am using is:

```
Processor       : ARM926EJ-Sid(wb) rev 0 (v5l)

BogoMIPS        : 331.77

Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java

CPU implementer : 0x41

CPU architecture: 5TEJ

CPU variant     : 0x0

CPU part        : 0x926

CPU revision    : 0

Cache type      : write-back

Cache clean     : cp15 c7 ops

Cache lockdown  : format C

Cache format    : Harvard
I size          : 32768
I assoc         : 1
I line length   : 32
I sets          : 1024
D size          : 32768
D assoc         : 1
D line length   : 32
D sets          : 1024

Hardware        : MV-88fxx81
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

My compile option on the ARM: `g++ -Wall SC_SCID.cpp`

How can I read the double precision type correctly on this processor? Are there any compiler options that I need to enable to correctly process double precision numbers on the ARM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would float point format be affected by big-endian and little endian?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242589/would-float-point-format-be-affected-by-big-endian-and-little-endian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between numbers like 41784.998495 and -8.1974E+204 is most likely a byte ordering issue -- Intel processors are little-endian, while ARMs are big-endian.  So if you write a binary file on one and want to read it on the other, you'll need to byte-swap the values.

Comment: "ARMs are big-endian" - huh? ARM CPUs are _bi_-endian, but are LE by default - not many systems run them in BE mode (although I'm not saying this _isn't_ one of them).

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs. The solution was indeed to rearrange the byte order. 
      
   `double swap(double d)`
    `{`
       `double a;`
       `unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char *)&a;`
       `unsigned char *src = (unsigned char *)&d;`
    
       `dst[0] = src[4];`
       `dst[1] = src[5];`
       `dst[2] = src[6];`
       `dst[3] = src[7];`
       `dst[4] = src[0];`
       `dst[5] = src[1];`
       `dst[6] = src[2];`
       `dst[7] = src[3];`
    
      ` return a;`
    `}`

[link] (http://www.screencast.com/t/Qqf40iy4Kc)

Comment: More of a Doubleword swap.

Answer (score 0):

**NB: This is a wiki answer; anyone may edit.**

As per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness), the ARM softfp emulation of `double` uses a mix of big and little endian.  The native format of the ARM926EJ is definitely **little endian** for integer types.

Read more in the question [*Would float point format be affected by big-endian and little endian?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242589/would-float-point-format-be-affected-by-big-endian-and-little-endian)